# Умножить каждый символ строки на его порядковый номер

Tags: python, строки

Нужно строки, содержащие символы строки s умножать на их порядковый номер.

```
s = str(input())
for i in range(len(s)-len(s[:3])):
        print(s[i])
        print(s[i+1]*2)
        print(s[i+2]*3)
        print(s[i+3]*4)
```

У меня получился такой код, но главная загвоздка в том, что слово может быть любой длины, и я уже долго не могу додуматься как это сделать. Помогите, пожалуйста!

Пример:

Sample Input:

```
back
```

Sample Output:

```
b
aa
ccc
kkkk
```

Comment: Покажите примеры задачи

Comment: ну функция len() вам знакома. Она применима к строке любой длины. Функция range() вам тоже известна. Она применима к любому числу. Т.е. все знания, необходимые для решения задачи, у вас имеются.

Comment: @Master'sTime 
Sample Input:
back /

Sample Output:
b
aa
ccc
kkkk

Comment: А что, если умножать не на 2,3, а на что-то в зависимости от i?

Comment: @MBo попробовал, ничего в голову не пришло..

Comment: Ну значит, не судьба...

Comment: Какой порядковый номер элемента c индексом i?

Comment: нулевой по идеи

Comment: 1) перебирайте не индексы, а прямо буквы самой строки, 2) используйте `enumerate`; дальше всё элементарно, только код записать

Comment: @CrazyElf да ну, с индексами же проще.

Comment: @Эникейщик А, ну да, можно и так. Просто не люблю индексирование %)

Answer (score 3):

Кроме комментаторов, ответ никто не дал, поэтому внесу свои 5 копеек:

```
s = str(input())
n = 0
for i in s:
    n += 1
    print(i*n)
```

Всё равно цикл проходит поочерёдно по символам, поэтому можно прибавлять значение переменной после каждой итерации и число будет равно порядковому номеру буквы в слове.

Comment: Да задача то элементарная, её можно решить кучей способов. Именно поэтому ответы обычно и не дают на такие задачи - если человек по таким задачам не хочет учиться, то он вообще ничему не научится. Пусть пытается решить.

Answer (score 2):

```
print(*(c*i for i, c in enumerate(input(), start=1)), sep='\n')
```

Comment: Лучше задать для enumerate параметр начала счета с единицы, если на то пошло

Comment: Можно, но это надо доку открывать, а так валяюсь в телефоне, лениво развлекаюсь...

Comment: Когда-то perl был весьма популярен, но потом обилие трудно читаемых однострочников в скриптах на нем все изменило. Может не стоит злоупотреблять?

Comment: тогда сайт превратится в "помогите не могу сложить 2+2"... интересных вопросов мало, пусть хотябы будут интересные ответы

Answer (score 1):

```
s = str(input())

for i in range(len(s)):

        print(i*s[i]+s[i])
```

Comment: Лучше умножить на `i+1`, чем добавлять тоже самое отдельно. Ну или `range` сделать от `1` до `len + 1`

Answer (score 1):

```
s = input()                # Не надо применить str() т.к. input() возвращает строку

for i, char in enumerate(s, start=1):
    print(i * char)
```

---

*Объяснение:*

Стандартная функция `enumerate()` нумерует символы строки, возвращая пары типа  **(порядковый_номер_символа, символ)**.

Например, `enumerate("Мама")` выдает постепенно пары

```
(0, "М") 
(1, "а") 
(2, "м") 
(1, "а")
```

Чтобы начать нумерование не нулей, а с числа 1, нужно добавить параметр `start=1`.

Answer (score 0):

Рекурсия:

```py
def f(word, times=1):
    if len(word) == 0:
        return
    print(word[0] * times)
    f(word[1:], times+1)

f("back")
```